# How to prevent a Meteor/Cordova App from connecting to 10.0.2.2? (And why does the app connect there?)

Tags: cordova, meteor, ddp

I have a Meteor app which runs on a local server for developement (http://10.0.2.10:3000). The `ROOT_URL` is set correctly so `__meteor_runtime_config__.ROOT_URL` equals this URL. Of course the app is working perfectly fine in the browser on a client computer within 10.0.2.0/24. The app is also working fine on mobile chrome/firefox on my android cell phone which is also part of 10.0.2.0/24. However when I try to run it as app on this cell phone with `meteor run android-device --mobile-server http://10.0.2.10:3000/` something strange happens:

When the app starts for the first time (or the first time after I clear all app data) it works like it should (content from the DB is loaded) for a few short seconds. Then the app reloads and any remote content from the DB isn't loaded anymore. I have added the following function to see where Meteor tries to connect to:

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
    console.log(__meteor_runtime_config__.ROOT_URL);
})
```

The first time when remote content is loaded this returns http://10.0.2.10:3000/ like I would expect. The second time when remote content isn't loaded it returns http://10.0.2.2:3000/.

The question now is, why is Meteor/Cordova doing this and how can I stop this behavior? Because obviously I cannot test the app this way. I'm not yet sure if it would work in production when I have a FQDN and HTTPS proxy but that's beyond the point.

I tried to find 10.0.2.2 as nothing in my LAN is running there and I have not specified this IP anywhere and found it in `/cordova-build/www/application/index.html` which seems to be generated from `boilerplate_web.cordova.html` (see this link https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/91819963/). However Meteor offers the possibility to override these generated files with a folder `cordova-build-override` and so I did removing the whole

```
if (/Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    //[...]
}
```

block and added a short `console.log('removed')`. This gets called so I know the override was successful and when I grep through the whole built .apk file 10.0.2.2 isn't found anymore - still the behavior is the same.

Any ideas what's going on and what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So even when you set your `ROOT_URL` correctly there are still special variables for mobile versions of it which do not get set and may contain `localhost`. And there seem to exist more code snippets in the meteor project which replace `localhost` with `10.0.2.2` aside from the one I mentioned above, when a Cordova client is connecting. So that seems to cause my app to reconnect to 10.0.2.2.

The mobile URL variables I could find are 
`process.env.MOBILE_ROOT_URL` and
`process.env.MOBILE_DDP_URL`. So in a `Meteor.startup()` function I now set those to my real `ROOT_URL` on the server side. My Android (Cordova) app now still is reconnecting a few seconds after its first start up but it's reconnecting to the same (and real) server URL (thus everything works fine)!

I still don't know why its reconnecting and those mobile variables and their use don't seem to be very well documented (or I missed something) but I can live with the way things work now.

Comment: Does this post explain your problem ? look at the rebolon answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34658956/meteorjs-mobile-build-rooturl-is-always-10-0-2-23000-instead-of-the-real-serv/34792259#34792259