# MeteorJS Mobile build : rooturl is always 10.0.2.2:3000 instead of the real server specified during build script

Tags: cordova, meteor

since few days i have some problem with meteorjs and mobile build.
The problem occurs with 3 differents apps.

I build the application with np scripting and this kind of script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -z "$npm_package_config_mongourl" ]; then echo "No mongourl config found in package.json"; else echo "set mongourl" && export MONGO_URL=$npm_package_config_mongourl; fi
if [ -z "$npm_package_config_mongooplogurl" ]; then echo "No mongooplogurl config found in package.json"; else echo "set mongooplogurl" && export MONGO_OPLOG_URL=$npm_package_config_mongooplogurl; fi
if [ -z "$npm_package_config_mailurl" ]; then echo "No mailurl config found in package.json"; else echo "set mailurl" && export MAIL_URL=$npm_package_config_mailurl; fi
if [ -z "$npm_package_config_rooturl" ]; then echo "No rooturl config found in package.json"; else echo "set rooturl" && export ROOT_URL=$npm_package_config_rooturl; fi
if [ -z "$npm_package_config_packagedirs" ]; then echo "No packagedirs config found in package.json"; else echo "set packagedirs" && export PACKAGE_DIRS=$npm_package_config_packagedirs; fi
if [ -z "$npm_package_config_mobileserver" ]; then echo "No mobile server config found in package.json (mobile app offline)" && export REBOLON_MOBILE_SERVER=""; else echo "set mobile server" && export REBOLON_MOBILE_SERVER=" --server=$npm_package_config_mobileserver"; fi
if [ -z "$npm_package_config_settingsfile" ]; then echo "No settings file found in package.json" && export REBOLON_SETTINGS=""; else echo "set settings" && export REBOLON_SETTINGS="--mobile-settings $npm_package_config_settingsfile"; fi

if [ -z "$npm_package_config_buildfolder" ]; then (
    echo "set a build folder before running the build system!"
    exit 1
); fi

meteor build $npm_package_config_buildfolder $REBOLON_SETTINGS $REBOLON_MOBILE_SERVER $*;
```

So once all env vars are created the meteor binary call looks like this :

```
meteor build ../../build/mobile --mobile-settings ./settings.json --server=http://myserver:3000
```

Then i inject the app into android emulator and i open a chrom remote debugger.
Then i run the app inside the emulator and i have strange behaviour :

- first the app seems to run well and connect to the server
- few seconds after it looks llike the app is refreshing and then it is connected to http://10.0.2.2:3000 instead of the original server uri

If i look at the debugger i can see that global var **meteor_runtime_config**.ROOT_URL is not the one set during the build command :

```
 {meteorRelease: "METEOR@1.2.1", PUBLIC_SETTINGS: Object, ROOT_URL: "http://10.0.2.2:3000", ROOT_URL_PATH_PREFIX: "", appId: "1rm26uv1lh7ui31i489b2"…}
```

The problem happens also with another app, but not after few seconds after the startup. In this app it occurs when i use the camera throught the app and when i select the photo then it come back to the app, but the ROOT_URL become http://10.0.2.2:3000

And finally with the third app, the problem occurs when i exit the app (or switch to the smartphone home per exemple) and i come back into the app. Then it refresh, and the ROOT_URL is 10.0.2.2:3000.

I don't have any clue to understand this. 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so i finally understood my errors :
MeteorJs is a full platform, and one app can be used to build cordova app, web site, and server.
When you build an app that has an android platform, you have to specify the --server parameter with the full uri of the server that will be used for DDP and cache application (--server=http://youServerIp:Port)
Then when you run your server, you must not forget to specify the mobile-server params because it will be used to configure the Cordova app when a new version of the application will be served to the smartphone (--mobile-server http://yourServerIp:Port)

Take care at one thing : 
 * for the build there is the sign "=" like this --server=http://youServerIp:Port
 * whereas when you run your server there is no sign like this --mobile-server http://yourServer:Port

In my case the build was good, which explain why at the first run of the app i had a connection to the server
So it was the server that was misconfigured because i never pass the mobile-server params. So when the server send the new version, it didn't send the server uri so the cordova app just consider that it was a client only application. And so when the app refreshed, it only connectes to it-self.

I have now modified my boilerpate to fix my start.sh scripts

Comment: I have exactly the same problem but I can't get the ROOT_URL to be set correctly. In fact, the generated Android project has the right adress in index.html but the apk has still the local adress. I found a workaround here https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7849#issuecomment-250763722

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the server? For example:

```
--server=http://192.168.1.1:3000
```

Comment: Yes this is the 6th " if " in the first code block. At app start, it connects to the server to get the appcache (so the --server options is well configured) but after that the webview refresh and then it connects to 10.0.2.2:3000